# Asynchronous Picture Upload to Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine

I'm writing a PHP Google App Engine app that allows users to upload multiple photos with a submission. Here's how I think it should go down:

1. The user selects the files to each section of the submission. This can be more than one file per section.
2. When the submit button is pressed, the app will iterate through all files on the page and get an "Upload to" url from my backend (generated by Google)
3. The frontend proceeds to upload the photo to the specified url. My backend returns an ID to be associated with that file now for reference.
4. Step 2 & 3 are repeated for each file on the page.
5. Once all files are uploaded and all IDs are acquired, the app can then submit the form along with the IDs it got during photo upload.

The reason I have no code to share with you is... well, I have none. I have the form written up to the image part. It just needs that feature before it's done. The backend implementation is going to be easy, I'm asking about the frontend. How would you do it and, if you could, samples would be great because I'm staring into a void with this one.

Thank you so much for any help. I'm really lost with this one.

Comment: you can actually send multiple files to one upload URL, no need to request one per file.

Comment: Right but I need the ID for each one of them without storing them on the server.

Comment: you could just send all ids back in one call, couldn't you?

Comment: No because each image(s) needs to stay attached to the section that it belongs to. The also each have descriptions so each one needs to be individually uploaded as I see it.